# Adding div inside another div which is being created by another jQuery script

Tags: jquery

I have the following code in a jQuery which generates a div class

```
if (!tst.g.ltContainer) {
      tst.g.ltContainer = $('<div>').addClass('tst-lt-container').addClass('tst-overflow-hidden').css({
        width: inner.width(),
        height: inner.height()
      }).prependTo(inner);
    }
    else {
      tst.g.ltContainer.empty().css({
        width: inner.width(),
        height: inner.height()
      });
    }
```

This will then be wrapped inside another div using the following:

```
$(el).find('.tst-layer').wrapAll('<div class="tst-inner"></div>');
```

Since to get this script to work was through adding stuff into the html it worked very well... Now I have to create it so it works with XML..

The issue is the following:

While parsing the xml I am creating all the divs that are required... issue is this one is not being constructed.

here is what I have written:

```
$(xml).find('first').each(function() {

        var container = $('<div></div>').appendTo(body);
        container.attr("id", "test-container");

        var first_style = $(this).attr('template.first.style');

        var first = $('<div></div>').appendTo(container);
        spot.attr("id", "placeholder");
        spot.attr("style", first_style);

        $(xml).find('second').each(function() {
            var second_style = $(this).attr('template.second.style');

            var second= $('<div></div>').appendTo(first);
            second.addClass("tst-layer");
            second.attr("style", second_style);

            var bg_src = $(this).attr('background');
            var background = $('<img/>').appendTo(item);
            background.addClass("tst-bg");
            background.attr("src", bg_src);
        })
    });
```

and this is what is being returned via the browser

```
     <div id="test-container">
<div id="placeholder" class="tst-container" style="width: 1906px; height: 953px; margin: 0px auto; visibility: visible;">
<div class="tst-inner" style="background-color: transparent; width: 1906px; height: 953px;">
<div class="tst-layer" style="width: 1906px; height: 953px; visibility: visible; display: none;">
```

when in fact it should be returning the following

```
<div id="test-container">
<div id="placeholder" class="tst-container" style="width: 1906px; height: 953px; margin: 0px auto; visibility: visible;">
<div class="tst-inner" style="background-color: transparent; width: 1906px; height: 953px;">
<div class="tst-lt-container tst-overflow-hidden" style="width: 1906px; height: 953px;">
<div class="tst-layer" style="width: 0px; height: 960px; visibility: visible; display: none; left: 0px; right: auto; top: 0px; bottom: auto;">
```

How can I get the tst-lt-container to be placed within the tst-inner when tst-inner?

Comment: No fiddle, too long, too exhausting